# Is the normal cone of a polyhedron a set of points or a set of vectors?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polyhedra, convex-geometry, locally-convex-spaces

I looked for the normal cone to a polyhedron, and I found this definition from [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr169-VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ertr/papers/rtr169-VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf):
[image: normal cone defintion]

But this is confusing to me.  it seems to me like the $\sum y_i a_i$ will yield a single value and not a vector.  it was my understanding that the normal cone is a set of vectors.

Is my understanding wrong?  Or am I misinterpreting what this book is saying for the Normal cone of a polyhedron??  thank.

Answer (score 1):

Note that on the right side of your formula for $N_C(\bar{x})$, there are **curly brackets** indicating this is a set. It is a special *set* of linear combinations with all coefficients being nonnegative. It is a finitely generated *convex cone*.

PS: You have found one of the finest math books ever written: Rockafellar-Wets's *Variational Analysis* - Have fun with it!

Comment: I see, the $a_i$'s are actually *vectors*, NOT elements of a single vector.  thank you @max_zorn.

Comment: Although, *technically* $a_i$ is a row vector.  So, I imagine they should actually all be transposed in order for the result of $\sum y_i a_i$ to be a column vector.  i.e. I think it should be $\sum y_i a_i^T$.  do you think so too @max_zorn?